# IP/host-based traffic grapher

Tags: linux, network-traffic, graph

Do you know/recommend any tool for graphing traffic based on IP or host? In this case, I will get a graph for every IP that passes through my gateway. Of course, I will use a predefined list of source IP addresses. This is useful to monitor the traffic usage of all hosts inside your network.

I am using nagios grapher to graph the network traffic, but this tool graph the total traffic passing through the system interface(s). Nagios uses a script to monitor the traffic of the interface. After that, the traffic data is passed to nagios grapher.

I need to install such a tool on my Linux server/gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at ntop.

Comment: Why is "look at ntop" or "look at atop" the common answer here?  What the user is trying to do is **visualize** their traffic, not look at a boring chart or linear graph.  I saw some responses to similar traffic lately that says that `iptables` is able to do some accounting.  Then, someone is going to have to poll those statistics and visualize them.  Standard model-view-controller problem.  Model the data using iptables, view as a graph, controller directs selected data to the graph.

Comment: ntop can visualize traffic based on IPs as described. zerolagtime, do you know of something that works better that you can contribute?

Comment: You could have just stated so in the first place (via your posted answer) and more effectively (than your comments). Here's a screen shot of ntop's abilities to fulfill what was described in the original question (not sure what you have against notp)... http://www.mid1.cz/images/ntop/ntop1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

[noah.org](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Packet_sniffing#etherape) lists quite a few tools that are good for examining, scraping, and visualizing network traffic.  So far, the one I find pretty interesting is `etherape`.  I even found out that some flash plugin is going to llwn.net (LimeWire!!!).  I'll be checking that out.  There were other tools there also that I liked but haven't tried out yet: darkstat, and ttt.  Both are on noah.org.  "[ttt](http://www.sonycsl.co.jp/person/kjc/kjc/software.html#ttt)" will also graph your bandwidth by protocol.

Turns out that llwn.net is a CDN for rhapsody.com.  Whew!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/), [pastmon](http://pastmon.sourceforge.net/Wikka-1.1.6.5/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage), [etherape](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/), [argus](http://www.qosient.com/argus/) try Google for more.

Answer (score 0):

Explore for **Cacti.** It's a really  good tool and opensource.