# Flexible traffic & bandwidth monitor

Tags: linux, bandwidth, traffic, monitoring

I have looked around, but have not found anything to meet our needs. I need something that can log all connections & bandwidth consumption. We need it for analysis: by protocol, source IP (& MAC if possible), destination, etc. Ideally we are looking for something that can produce custom graphs & also uses mysql. All connections go through one server on a bridged connection (2 network cards) so it is easy to pickup traffic. We are not concerned so much with internal LAN traffic as what passes in & out to the firewall. Thanks for you suggestions.

**Update**: I use Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: We use Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, I posted a question about IP/host-based network traffic grapher. I am not sure if it will meet all your requirements. Have a look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/196626/ip-host-based-traffic-grapher). I tried ntop and it seems to be a very good tool.

Comment: okay, I'll have a look at ntop and see if it does what we need. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, ntop works well. You can have it work with mysql like I wanted, but I will have to figure out exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Analog-X  Netstat Live](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/nsl/Freeware.htm) is totally free.